Existence of antiderivative w.r.t. any given multi-index for tempered distributions
I originally posted this question on ME, but I find it a lot more nontrivial than expected. So, I post it here.
Let $T$ be a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, it is a well-known regularity result that there eixsts a polynomially bounded continuous function $g$ and a multi-index $\beta$ such that $T=D^\beta g$ in the distributional sense. That is, for any $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have
\begin{equation}
T(f)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (-1)^{\lvert \beta \rvert} g(x) (D^\beta f)(x) d^nx
\end{equation}
However, this result only states that there exists "some" multi-index $\beta$ with respect to which a distributional anti-derivative of $T$ exists.
I wonder if for "any given" $\beta$, we can find such an anti-derivative of $T$. That is,

For a tempered distribution $T$, can we find a tempered distribution $g_{\beta}$ for each multi-index $\beta$ such that $T = D^\beta g_\beta$ in the distributional sense?

I am not sure if this is true. Could anyone help me?
Update) As in this ME post, the sign function $x \to \text{sgn}(x)$ does not have an antiderivative in the ordinary sense. However, it does have an antiderivative in the distributional sense. So, things look quite indecisive for me..

$\newcommand\be\beta\newcommand\vpi\varphi\newcommand\S{\mathcal S}\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$Here is an explicit and elementary solution, without using the fact that $T=D^\be f$ for some continuous function $f$.
Without loss of generality, $\be=(1,0,\dots,0)$.
Consider first the case $n=1$. We want to find some $g\in\S'(\R)$ such that $g'=T$ -- that is,
$$g(\psi')=-T(\psi) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $\psi\in\S$.
Note that $\vpi\in\S(\R)$ is the derivative of a function $\psi$ in $\S(\R)$ iff $\int\vpi=0$. So, $g$ is identified up to an additive constant by the known action of $g$ on all functions in $\S(\R)$ with $\int\vpi=0$.
Accordingly, pick any $\psi\in\S(\R)$ with $\int\psi\ne0$ and complete the definition of $g$ by assigning some real value to $g(\psi)$. For instance, letting $g(\psi):=0$, for all $\vpi\in\S(\R)$ one has
$$g(\vpi)=-T(\Psi_\vpi),$$
where
$$\Psi_\vpi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x dt\,\vpi_\psi(t) \tag{2}\label{2} $$
for real $x$ and
$$\vpi_\psi:=\vpi-\frac{\int\vpi}{\int\psi}\,\psi.$$
Then \eqref{1} will hold.
Moreover, the so defined linear functional $g$ is continuous, because $\int f$ is continuous in $f\in\S(\R)$ (say at $f=0$). The latter continuity follows in view of de la Vallée-Poussin theorem (or its appropriate modification).

Similarly, for any $n\ge1$, a "partial antiderivative" $g$ of $T$ "wrt to the first coordinate of a point in $\R^n$"
is identified by the known action of $g$ on the partial derivatives wrt to the first coordinate of all functions in $\S(\R^n)$ -- just up to an additive tempered distribution $C$ that does not depend on the first coordinate of a point (that is, the partial derivative of $C$ wrt to the first coordinate is $0$).
In this more general case, one can say that $g$ is identified up to an additive $C$ as above by the known action of $g$ on all functions $\vpi\in\S(\R^n)$ such that $\int_\R\vpi(x_1,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1=0$ for all $(x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\R^{n-1}$.
Here, instead of the integration in \eqref{2}, use the "partial" integration wrt to the first coordinate.

For general $\beta$, you define $g_0$ by $g_0( D^\beta \psi) := (-1)^{\lvert \beta \rvert} T(\psi)$. for all $\psi \in \mathcal{S}$ so that $g_0$ is a continuous linear functional on the linear subspace of $ \mathcal{S}$ given by ${ D^\beta \psi \mid \psi \in \mathcal{S} }$?

Then, you use the Hahn Banach theorem to extend $g_0$ to an element $g \in \mathcal{S}'$?

@Isaac : Yes, you can do this.

Then, by construction, $D^\beta g = T$ in the distributional sense.

Wait, it is not clear to me why $g_0$ is continuous on the linear subspace. Does uniform convergence of all derivatives equal or higher than $D^\beta$ imply convergence of lower-order derivatives too?

@Isaac : The topology on the subspace is induced by that on the entire space, which involves the derivatives of all orders.

Let ${ f_n } \subset { D^\beta \psi \mid \psi \in \mathcal{S}}$ be a convergent sequence. By definition, there exists $\psi_n \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $f_n = D^\beta \psi_n$ for each $n$. From convergence of $f_n$, we only know that derivatives of $\psi_n$ equal or higher than $\beta$ converge uniformly.

@Isaac : Good point. I have now retained only the most elementary and explicit part, without using the Hahn--Banach theorem.

OK, I can see. However, it is still not clear to me why your $g$ is continuous. If $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $\mathcal{S}$, do we have $\Psi_{\phi_n} \to \Psi_\phi$ in $\mathcal{S}$?

$\lVert \Psi_{\phi_n} - \Psi_\phi \rVert_\infty \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert \phi_n - \phi \rvert$ but I have difficulty proving that the rhs tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.

@Isaac : I added a detail on that.

I don't think we need those fancy theorems to show continuity of your $g$. Look at this ME post. It is quite an elementary estimate that I completely forgot...

Since you already mentioned the standard result that for any tempered distribution $T$, we have $T=D^{\gamma}f$ for some $\gamma$ and some polynomially bounded continuous function $f$, you can also take a suitable anti-derivative $h$ of $f$, so $D^{\beta}h=f$, and then $g=D^{\gamma}h$ will satisfy $D^{\beta}g=T$, as desired.
Note that no advanced tools are required to find $h$ as $f$ is continuous, so we can just integrate this function in calculus style.

Oops, I was dumb....but could you tell me a bit more in detail how you take a "suitable" anti-derivative?

@Isaac: Yes, I guess "suitable" was bad style and doesn't mean anything here, delete (in your mind) if desired. I just meant any $h$ such that $D^{\beta}h=f$.

So, I guess $D^\beta h =f$ can be established in the ordinary sense.

@Isaac: Yes, repeated one-dimensional integrations will work fine, as in your formula (though I think the details are a bit off, order of integrals and the lower limit in the second integral should be a constant, not $y_2$).

I re-write here to give a correct example : for $n=2$ and $\beta=(1,2)$ we fix some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $h(x_1,x_2):=\int_c^{x_2} \int_b^{y_2} \int_a^{x_1} f(t_1,t_2) dt_1 dt_2 dy_2$.

I find your answer very simple and elegant, but I feel obliged to vote for the answer of Prof. Iosif Pinelis, as he has put huge amount of efforts into answering me with explicit computations...I am sorry about this.

@Isaac: No worries, that's fine.

I have run into another issue. Could you help me with this one as well?

Any linear pde with constant coefficients on $\cal S´$ has a solution.

True but more involved than the other answers, since it uses a theorem of Hormander, Lojasiewicz, and later Atiyah.

It is a matter of common courtesy to acknowledge that one is proving a very special case  of a known result, in this case  one of the central theorems of pde theory.
